# Multiple Forms instance with backgroundworker

Tags: .net, vb.net, backgroundworker, multiple-instances, onpaint

I have 2 forms: "main" and "panel".
Main form contains 2 buttons: "bt_panel1" and "bt_panel2".
The each button's function is:

```
Private Sub bt_panel1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles bt_panel1.Click
    Dim panel1_run As New panel
    panel1_run.PANEL_NUM = 1
    panel1_run.Name = "panel1_run"
    panel1_run.Text = "PANEL 1"
    panel1_run.Show()
End Sub
```

(about bt_panel2, "2" instead of "1")

Panel form contains:

- function load:

```
Private Sub panel_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    [...]
    'create 80 picturboxes 
    For i = 1 To 4
       For k = 1 To 20
          Dim picture As New PictureBox
          picture.Name = "pic" & i & "c" & k
          [...]
          Controls.Add(picture)
          AddHandler picture.Paint, AddressOf paintchar
       Next
    Next
    'start BackgroundWorker
     BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

- a backgroundworker control (which does something irrelevant) and its "RunWorkerCompleted":

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim temp As PictureBox
    Try
       For i = 1 To 4
           For k = 1 To 20
               'for each picturebox call refresh (paintchar)
                temp = Me.Controls.Item("pic" & i & "c" & k)
                temp.Refresh()
           Next
       Next
       'restart BackgroundWorker1 continuosly
       BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Error BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

- function paint:

```
Private Sub paintchar(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
   [...]
   Try
      e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LawnGreen, New RectangleF(loc, size))
   Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error paintchar" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
   End Try
End Sub
```

**If I open only one panel (pressing bt_panel1 or bt_panel2 in Main) everything is ok.**
But if I open both panels (pressing bt_panel1 and bt_panel2 in Main) application does not respond and panel2 is totally blank (non painted). 
Application does not respond (I can't close panel and I can't close Main... I must terminate debug to close).
Exceptions are not called.
ReportProgress function is not used.
DoWork functions reads some data from a SharedMemory area (different data for panel1 and 2) 
I think the problem is with the "Me.Controls" in RunWorkerCompleted that is not referenced to the corresponding instance of the form.

Comment: Is there an exception or a message included with the application crash? If yes, you should include it in your question. It'll provide valuable information.

Comment: Catching exceptions and not reporting them is a good way to have code misbehave without having any idea why.  The assumption that a BackgroundWorker is irrelevant with this kind of problem is a mistake.  You will freeze the UI with a deadlock or by calling ReportProgress too often.

Comment: no, there aren't exceptions. Application does not respond (I can't close panel and I can't close Main... I must terminate debug) and panel2 is totally blank (non painted).

Answer (score 0):

AS I understand the Background worker you can not reference the UI or its controls from inside the Background worker thread so your thought that the me.cosntrols statement was somehow at fault is likely correct.